# how to get data from dynamic table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get data from chosen table of my database?
I'm going to work with database in c# application and I have the database includes that tables:

1. **MyTable1;**
2. **MyTable2;**
3. **...**

And I have **tbl** variable that is equal to `tbl = "MyTable2";`. I want to execute the code as following:`select * from tbl`

---

I try to execute this code:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     (
          SELECT TABLE_NAME
          FROM   information_schema.tables
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable1'
          );
```

But the code returned error that *Every derived table must have its own alias*

---

I want to get all data from table whose name is equal to my variable (**tbl**) and its value can also be changed. How can I do it?

Comment: @ADyson That won't do the job, because dynamic SQL is needed to build a query this way.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this using a prepared statement in MySQL:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
INTO @table
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable1';

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @table);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: You don't need to run the first query with PREPARE/EXECUTE, you can just run the query normally and store its result in the `@table` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (
      SELECT TABLE_NAME
      FROM   information_schema.tables
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable1'
      ) AS Blah
```

Comment: That solves the table alias issue, but it doesn't do what the OP wants, which is to substitute the table name and query from that table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SELECT nvarchar(500)
SET @SELECT = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tbl
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SELECT
```